# Why Kafka stops with an error on log dirs?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to learn kafka and I had the below error:

```
[2021-01-21 13:46:43,247] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=0] Broker 0 stopped fetcher for partitions
__consumer_offsets-22,first_topic-2,__consumer_offsets-37,first_topic-0,__consumer_offsets- 
38,__consumer_offsets-13,twitter_tweets-5,__consumer_offsets-30,twitter_tweets-3,__consumer_offsets-
8,__consumer_offsets-21,__consumer_offsets-4,__consumer_offsets-27,__consumer_offsets- 
7,__consumer_offsets-9,__consumer_offsets-46,new_topic-0,__consumer_offsets-25,__consumer_offsets- 
35,twitter_tweets-0,__consumer_offsets-41,__consumer_offsets-33,__consumer_offsets- 
23,__consumer_offsets-49,__consumer_offsets-47,__consumer_offsets-16,__consumer_offsets- 
32,__consumer_offsets-40 and stopped moving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log 
directory C:\kafka_2.13-2.6.0\data\kafka. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2021-01-21 13:46:43,252] WARN Stopping serving logs in dir C:\kafka_2.13-2.6.0\data\kafka 
(kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-01-21 13:46:43,254] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\kafka_2.13-2.6.0\data\kafka have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

This happens every time I run a command for example:

`bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic streams-plaintext-input`.

When I delete all the offsets in /data folder then everything run smoothly. Is this happening because of the 7 day existing period that Kafka has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is that Kafka depends on POSIX filesystem semantics that don't work well on windows.

> Kafka uses specific features of POSIX to achieve high performance, so emulations—which happen on WSL 1—are insufficient. For example, the broker will crash when it rolls a segment file

This appears to be the error you're mentioning about the segment retention

If you want to use Kafka on windows, WSL2 is the suggested solution.

https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Also note: --zookeeper flag is deprecated